# Cancel all user orders on subscription cancelled/expired

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I want to develop a setup/code in which all the orders made by the user gets cancelled when the his subscription gets cancelled or expired. I am using Wordpress, Woocommerce and Woocommerce Subscriptions plugin.

I am trying to do by using something like this:

```
function my_cancelled_subscription( $user_id, $subscription_key ) {

    //what code should I use here????
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_status_cancelled', 'my_cancelled_subscription', 10, 2 );
```

Please help mee.....

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out..........

```
function my_cancelled_subscription( $subscription ) {
    
    $order_id = $subscription->get_parent_id();
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
    $order->update_status( 'cancelled' );
    
    $args = array(
        'customer_id' => $user_id,
        'status' => 'wc-completed',
    );
    $arrorders = wc_get_orders( $args );
    
    foreach ($arrorders as $ord) {
        $ord->update_status( 'cancelled' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_status_cancelled', 'my_cancelled_subscription' );
```

Comment: Please note this only triggers when a user's subscription gets cancelled. If you want to add triggers for different subscription states them add more actions to call this custom function.